# XMLException was unhandled 'var' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read xml node values from a xml file. But when I do it throws this exception:

> System.Xml.XmlException: 'src' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 29, position 19.
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
>    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
>    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
>    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
>     at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
>     at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
>    at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
>     at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
>     at ToolkitM9.RVersion.Window_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in
>   f:\Development\ToolkitM9\ToolkitM9\RVersion.xaml.cs:line 48

This is my code:

```
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load("Version.xml");

            XmlNodeList name = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Name");
            XmlNodeList ver = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Version");
            XmlNodeList notes = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Notes");
            XmlNodeList openSite = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("openSite");
            XmlNodeList link = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Link");

            MessageBox.Show(
            "Name: " + name[0].InnerText + "\n" +
            "Version: " + ver[0].InnerText + "\n" +
            "Notes: " + notes[0].InnerText + "\n" +
            "Open Link? " + openSite[0].InnerText + "\n" +
            "Link: " + link[0].InnerText + "\n"
```

This is my XML file:

```
 <Recovery>
    <Name>TWRP</Name>
    <Version>2.5.0.3</Version> 
    <Notes>There are some bugs remaining in this build. See here..</Notes>
    <openSite>true</openSite>
    <Link>http://google.com</Link>
 </Recovery>
```

Thanks for any assistance! :)

Comment: Since there isn't any src or = in your xml sample I doubt that you are loading the correct file. Are you somehow loading this file from a webserver or similar before you try to parse it?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I forgot to mention! I used:
`xDoc.Load("https://s.basketbuild.com/dl/devs?dl=squabbi/m9/recoveries/" + ToolkitM9.Properties.Settings.Default["Device"] + "/Version.xml");`

Where `ToolkitM9.Properties.Settings.Default["Device"]` is a variable. e.g _GSM_

Comment: Exactly, so the "xml" you are parsing isn't what you expect it to be but rather some error message as html. Since it seems to work when accessing it via a regular browser it probably expects some headers to be sent like User-Agent, Accepts or otherwise that XmlDocument won't set for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. Notice I am using `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`, not `XmlDocument`. While `XDocument` is preferred, I don't think the use of `XmlDocument` is your problem. I agree with @Karl-Johan Sjogren that you probably aren't parsing what you think you are, although I disagree about needing to set headers. Skipping the file and directly loading the URI is successful:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("https://s.basketbuild.com/dl/devs?dl=squabbi/m9/recoveries/GSM/Version.xml");
var name = doc.Root.Element("Name").Value;
var version = doc.Root.Element("Version").Value;
var notes = doc.Root.Element("Notes").Value;
var site = doc.Root.Element("openSite").Value;
var link = doc.Root.Element("Link").Value;
Console.WriteLine(name);
Console.WriteLine(version);
Console.WriteLine(notes);
Console.WriteLine(site);
Console.WriteLine(link);
```